# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey Builder sms

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I have a question regarding Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey Builder. We have a requirement from our client to build a Journey that involves sending both emails and SMS to the audience. Our client did not choose to send the SMS via Mobil Studio standard functionality. Instead we are calling a web service that will receive as input parameters the receiver phone number, SMS Message...and other parameters.

My question is what standard functionality can we use (if something is available) in order to send the SMS from Journey Builder.

We proposed to send SMS messages via Automation Studio using a Script Activity (Server Side Java Script that invokes the SMS web service). This option was not accepted by our client, they want to send both the SMS and emails from Journey Builder as mentioned above.

As a possible solution we were thinking to try to connect Marketing Cloud to a Salesforce environment and in Journey builder add a step to interact with salesforce (Create a Task). In the input fields for the new task we would map all the required information in order to send the SMS from Salesforce APIs (we would do the call to the SMS gateway from Salesforce based on a trigger on Task object).

Can you please give us a better solution to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: IMO, that's the best solution I could recommend using Journey builder.  Does your SMS gateway supports email integration? You could send an email to SMS gateway and then can trigger the SMS.

Answer (score 1):

For sending SMS through an external service provider, one option is to get the external web service provider to create a custom **Marketing Cloud Package** to pass the contact data from Marketing Cloud to the web service. This will create an activity in Journey Builder that will pass the necessary contact details to the external web service for sending SMS.

Official Marketing Cloud Package documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/index.htm).

Once you have the package details from the services provider (API key and endpoint URL etc), you can follow these steps for the custom activity to appear in Journey Builder:

1. Go to Settings > Administration.
2. Go to Account > Installed Packages.
3. Click New to add your custom package.
4. Define a name and description and click Save.
5. Click Add Component to add customer journey activity to the package.
6. Pick Journey Builder Activity.

Answer (score 0):

To send an SMS from the Journey Builder:
**1**. In Contact Builder, the journey Data Extension should be mapped to all Contacts using Data Designer.

[image]

**2**. You need to create an SMS in MobileStudio (MobileConnect), note that send method is Interaction. (As shown in below screenshot)

[image]

**3**. Drag and drop the SMS and configure.
[image]

Comment: Dorjee - the issue is, that the question specifically mentions the inability to use the native SMS feature of Mobile Studio, as an external system is being used to send out the messages. And this needs integrating, so the Send SMS step is not a viable solution.